# CPU timer in C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, timer

```
unsigned char ticks_bits[3] = { 0x0F, 0x31, 0xC3};
__uint64_t ( * ticks ) () = (__uint64_t (*) ()) & ticks_bits;

__uint64_t T = ticks(); // CRASH!
```

I have used this code for many years in Windows-32bit to get CPU ticks.
But it will crash in Linux 64bit. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Eek, executable code on the stack? That's a really bad idea ... Seriously, just use the standard library functions.

Comment: It will also crash on Windows XP SP2 and later - Data Execution Prevention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done in the past is something like this:

```
uint64_t
clock_ticks()
{
  uint64_t ret;

  __asm__ volatile (".byte 0x0f, 0x31" : "=A" (ret));

  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Why `.byte` instead of the mnemonic?